# handelbar js - if and data at a same time is not working inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am trying to get json data value, if it is there means it will display or else that whole element will not be there, but its not working with handlebar js

```
var data = {
    listBank: [
      {  
                     "enableSavedCards":"false",
                     "enableAxisAccount":"true",
                     "enableCreditCards":"false",
                     "enableNetBanking":"false",
                     "enableDebitCards":"false"
                  },
       {  
           "sample":"valuesample",
       "sample2":"valuesample2"


                  }

                  ]
};
```

here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/1myd7s5o/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are referencing the handlebars library, along with jQuery.
Here is your jsfiddle with these files referenced.
Also, the true/false values in the JSON data have been updated to remove the quotes to enable the IF statements in your code:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmetqz5L/)

```
  listBank: [{
  "enableSavedCards": false,
  "enableAxisAccount": true,
  ....
```